# HList elements to match type classes type parameter

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to implement something similar to Slick's Table and Column definitions using Shapeless.

This code will be working with a 3rd-party Java library so and at some point I need to convert the HList to an `Array[Any]`.

Even though what follows seems to be working, it doesn't look like the right way to go about it:

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist._

trait ColumnType[A]

object ColumnType {
  implicit object StringType extends ColumnType[String]
  implicit object IntType extends ColumnType[Int]
  implicit object BooleanType extends ColumnType[Boolean]
}

case class Column[T : ColumnType](name: String, description: String)

trait Logger[L <: HList] {
  val columns: L

  object javaTypes extends Poly1 {
    implicit def caseInt = at[Int](i => new java.lang.Integer(i))
    implicit def caseString = at[String](identity)
    implicit def caseBoolean = at[Boolean](b => new java.lang.Boolean(b))
  }

  object extract extends Poly1 {
    implicit def caseT[T : ColumnType] = at[Column[T]](_.asInstanceOf[T])
  }

  def apply[P <: Product, M <: HList](p: P)(
    implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[P, L],
    mapper: Mapper.Aux[javaTypes.type, L, M]
  ): List[Any] = gen.to(p).map(javaTypes).runtimeList
}
```

A `Logger` will be defined like:

```
class AccessLog extends Logger[String :: Int :: Boolean :: HNil] {
  val path = Column[String]("path", "uri path")
  val statusCode = Column[Int]("statusCode", "status code")
  val authenticated = Column[Boolean]("authenticated", "is user authenticated")

  val columns = HList(path, statusCode, authenticated).map(extract)
}
```

And will be used:

```
val accessLog = new AccessLog

accessLog("1", 2, false).foreach(p => println(s"$p: ${p.getClass}"))
```

The requirements are that the type of `columns` should match the type parameter of the Logger and also a way to convert the passed values to Java types.

I'm particularly uneasy on the way that `extract` is defined.

Comment: The `asInstanceOf` call only succeeds at runtime because of type erasure. The actual runtime type of `accessLog.columns` is `Column[String] :: Column[Int] :: Column[Boolean] :: HNil`. In absence of any default values, what would you expect the value of `accessLog: String :: Int :: Boolean :: HNil` to be?